# Looking for tool that prevent script to become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

For a side project, I need to generate a lot of data from a WebGL Application. This Web App is mostly a personal tool and I really don't care if my browser becomes unresponsive (I mean, I know it will).

I would like to prevent my browser from displaying this popup:
[image: chrome unresponsive crash popup]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible the script keeps running while Chrome waits for you to click the button.  In which case, it doesn't really matter if you're not clicking on the button (unless the button is modal and you're trying to work in another tab).

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was thinking that the script was already "Stopped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has an option Dom.max_script_run_time. I don't know if such a thing exists in Chrome, but I wouldn't bet on it. It's probably easiest just to run this script in FF.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.max_script_run_time